# The method isEnabled is set true but the user is not able to login

Tags: php, symfony

I have implemented the AdvancedUserInterface and I'm using the method isEnaled to check if the user has confirmed his email, but even when the method returns true, when I try to login always returns the message "User account is locked."

I'm using mysql to persist the data

Code from my user entity

```
/**
* @ORM\Column(type="boolean", name="is_active")
*/
private $isActive;

public function getIsActive() {
     return $this->isActive;
}

public function setIsActive($isActive) {
    $this->isActive = $isActive;
}

public function isEnabled() {
    return $this->getIsActive();
}
```

My login controler

```
$authenticationUtils = $this->get('security.authentication_utils');

$error = $authenticationUtils->getLastAuthenticationError();

$lastEmail = $authenticationUtils->getLastUserName();

return $this->render('Login/login.html.twig', array(
    'last_username' => $lastEmail,
    'error'         => $error,
));
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out that symfony login first run the functions isAccountNonExpired, isCredentialsExpired and isAccountLocked, that where all empty on my code, and for last runs isEnabled.
Just a stupit noobie mistake.